# How to detect that code is running in service worker offline mode

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Service workers enable you to cache files that will be run when the user goes into offline mode. Here is sample code:

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'my-site-cache-v1';
var urlsToCache = [
  '/',
  '/styles/main.css',
  '/script/main1.js',
  '/script/main2.js'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        console.log('Opened cache');
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
      })
  );
});
```

So you define a list of files [main.css, main1.js, and main2.js] to be cached, that will be loaded when the user goes offline.

In the `main1.js` file, I want to define some code to run only when the file is loaded by the service worker in offline mode. Is there some way to detect this?

```
if(script_is_loaded_by_sw_in_offline_mode_not_online)
{
    //do some stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `navigator.onLine` to detect whether the browser is in online or offline mode ,as the service worker  will be registered regardless of the online mode or offline mode and the main1.js file will always be cached as you have added it to urlsToCache , you can use  `navigator.onLine` in the main1.js file to check the condition you want.

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.onLine` is one of the solutions, but there is a problem with that:

if you are connected to a wireless network but there is no internet access, navigator is unable to detect the true network status and still returns true (Online).

### More Reliable Solution :

you can provide a **backend api** which does an internet ping (4.2.2.4) and return you a **boolean** result .

`/api/ping ===> true | false`

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that `navigator.serviceWorker.controller` is what I needed:

```
if(navigator.serviceWorker.controller)
{
    //do some stuff here
}
```